# Actionbar text not changed to custom font after using Calligraphy library

Tags: android, fonts, androiddesignsupport, custom-font, android-typeface

I am using Calligraphy library and it working fine except in Actionbar. I am using the below lines for Calligraphy to work

in OnCreate():

```
 CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Regular.ttf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build());
```

And

```
  @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

Using Above all fonts are customized except in Action Bar. Any other steps need to add?

Tried with below but error saying cannot resolve constructor

```
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My Title");
s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "MyTypeface.otf"), 0, s.length(),
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Any options? Calligraphy version -  compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html#add-toolbar). Check [this comment](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/181#issuecomment-197730013) from Calligraphy:

> I don't support the action bar, only toolbars. It's too much to
>   maintain otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom view for your action bar (it will display between your icon and your action items). Refer here for what can be done https://recalll.co/app/?q=android%20-%20How%20to%20Set%20a%20Custom%20Font%20in%20the%20ActionBar%20Title?

Also get some more details here
https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/11

Hope this helps.